# How to set up a home page in WordPress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm a newbie in WordPress. I wrote my custom theme. I have a problem with how to set up a home page and blog page.

So now I have created a blog page and set up a separate WordPress Blog Page for posts, and this is fine. I clicked on the menu "Post" and I'm directed to the post page.

But the problem is with the home menu. In index.php I have the following:

```
<?php get_header() ?>

<div>
  <?php 
    while(have_posts()){ the_post();
        get_template_part('content',''); // => this is my posts page
    } ?>
</div>

<?php get_footer() ?>
```

When I come to the home page I see my page with style from content.php where I have all posts. Why index.php see my CSS style(from content.php) if I'm not on content.php. Also I created in admin-php home page with my custom text. WP sees this text, with CSS style from custom.php

Comment: To display posts use a gutenberg widget or code it to your template: https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-display-recent-posts-in-wordpress/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have a template that is used for your homepage you have to create  a file named `front-page.php`. You can read [this Article in the Theme Developer Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/custom-front-page-templates/) for more information.